# Is it possible to root an android phone while a specific application is running?

Tags: rooting

Basically I'm using SafetyNet by Google to check at the beginning whenever my application is opened to see if a phone is rooted. If it is, I'll prevent my app from running. So as you can tell if it is possible to root an android phone while a specific app is running, then what I'm doing can be bypassed. So is it possible?

Comment: It's even possible to root while the recovery is booted, thus with Android (and apps) inactive.

Comment: Here's a comment from the other end (the end-user): even if you put a root blocker in your app, there are easy ways of getting around it. Can you explain why you don't want root?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question right, you have an app and you wish to detect if the phone is rooted, and if it is, than you stop your app from running?

If that's the case I am not sure. Simply because, what code can you write in your app that checks if your phone is rooted or not? Since the user is the king in that case, and your app is not system app but rather a third party if you will, you have a limited set of permissions you can ask from the user to give you. None of these permissions will help you however to determine if the phone is rooted or not. Hence, as far as I know, not possible. However if you ever stumble across some hack that let's you do it, please let me know :)

Comment: Pardon me, isn't root detection one of the most obvious things SafetyNet does? Developers just need to make use of the API. OP already said he plans to use it to detect root environment; the problem is whether SN detects an *ongoing* root process.

Comment: Than I didn't get the question right, I was thinking the OP wants to bypass SafetyNet actions upon detection of device. Sorry for the confusion. To answer the question finally than, in theory it is. I don't think SN supports the option of tracking an ongoing rooting process and hence it's detection. But than again when you root your phone it usually needs to restart. When your app is started again (after restart of the device), the SN starts with it too, and than it detects the device and everything should work properly (in theory).

Comment: How did they do this with Pokemon GO?

Comment: @Dejan Not every one-clickers reboot the phone, as my (limited) experience with one-clickers have shown... But yeah that's one reasonable point.

Comment: So if it is possible if the user roots their phone using king root(or any rooter that doesn't require a full reboot), then what would be a counter for this? Instead of checking only once whenever the app is run in the beginning, start a background service thread in the app that routinely calls safetynet every X amount of duration of time and act accordingly?

Comment: @RichyDavisWindow3 That would most probably be one possible solution. In fact, to be honest I don't see any other. It may put some weight on your app performance, but if your main goal is to keep rooted phones away from your app at all times I guess it's worth the price (of course, I don't think it will affect it so the user notices it, depends on implementation). Since I don't know the concept of your app I can't really tell you much more. At this moment it all comes down to what is the most important aspect for your app :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to root your phone with third party applications like king root.. Yes you can root with background applications running. BG apps should not be a problem.. But if you want to do it by the standard method.. You ll have to close all background apps. Sorry if my answer was inappropriate to your question

Comment: So if it is possible if the user roots their phone using king root, then what would be a counter for this? Instead of checking only once whenever the app is run in the beginning, start a background service thread in the app that routinely calls safetynet every X amount of duration of time and act accordingly?

Comment: @RichyDavisWindow3 This isn't a developer site, so I'm afraid we can't really advise you how to write your app.